# Possible to make non-editable Text() secure?

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to make a non-editable `Text` display black circles instead of the string (same as what a `SecureField` would display). The closest I can find is to make a `SecureField` and add `.disabled(true)`, but `Text` can just have normal `String` type as its content while `SecureField` needs a `Binding<String>`. What I am looking for is something like this

```
Group {
    if visible {
        Text(content)
    } else {
        // SecureText(content)                   <- looking for a class
        // Text(content).turnContentIntoCircles  <- or an attribute
        SecureField("",text:bindingContent)  //  <- cannot use variable 'content: String'
            .disabled(true)           
    }
}
.font(.title3)
```

Is the technology there yet?

Comment: What do you mean by "make [it] secure"? You want to display the characters as `*`? You want to make in non-selectable? Can you clarify the goal?

Comment: Or maybe you're just looking to use `.constant(bindingContent)` in `SecureField`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just edited my question. I want `Text` to display black circles instead of the string (same as what a `SecureField` would display). `.constant(bindingContent)` is not what I am looking for because I am trying to avoid creating extra variable `bindingContent`.

Comment: No need to create `bindingContent` -- you could just use `.constant(content)`

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, and I finally get what you are saying, you meant `SecureField("", text: .constant(content))`, not `SecureField("", text: bindingContent).constant(content)`. I never used `.constant()` before and I like this approach very much. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, works for me:

```
Text(String(repeating: "⚫", count: content.count))
```

You can also use this:

```
Text(String(repeating: "\u{1F910}", count: content.count))
```

Comment: Oh my God!!! This is the dark technology I am looking for. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: The Dark Lord has spoken, ha ha, and if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it, using the tick mark, it turns green.